# A Simple Provably Secure Key Exchange Scheme Based on the Learning with Errors Problem

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe

In [this](http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/b1e7/faec59a9bdd70e75f9d15496cf27916ce060.pdf) paper (A simple provably secure key exchange by Ding et al.)  At page number 8, the author gives correctness of the technique as follows
[image]

then SK <sub>A</sub>  = SK<sub>B</sub> with overwhelming probability i.e. if Alice and Bob run the protocol honestly, then they will share an identical key.

The above equation uses Lemma 1 which is as follows

[image]

How does the author deduce the above equation using Lemma 1. This equation gives correctness of the technique. Can anyone please help.

Comment: There's a reference to Lemma 1 in what you've reproduced. That lemma's the key.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How he used lemma 1 to produce this equation

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now. You should add lemma 1 to the question so someone else can use it in their answer.

Comment: Please see the related posted question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/a-simple-provably-secure-key-exchange-scheme-based-on-the-lwe Thanks

Comment: Please see this bquestion https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48566/provably-secure-password-authenticated-key-exchange-based-on-rlwe-for-the-post-q

Comment: @Michael Snook I have started a chat related to cryptanalysis of your published paper. Please see it here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62701/pake-based-on-rlwe

Comment: I have started a chat related to cryptanalysis of key exchange given by Ding et al. based RLWE. Please see it here chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62701/pake-based-on-rlwe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: Lemma 1 says that $||\mathbf{x}|| \leq \alpha q \sqrt{n}$ with overwhelming probability if $\mathbf{x}$ is drawn from the discrete Gaussian since $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is negligible.

Next, from properties of absolute values, $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$. So, leaving the $2$ out for now and writing $\mathbf{s_A}^T\mathbf{e_B}$ as $\mathbf{s_A}\cdot\mathbf{e_B}$:

$|\mathbf{s_A}\cdot\mathbf{e_B} + e'_A + \mathbf{s_B}\cdot\mathbf{e_A} + e'_B| \leq |\mathbf{s_A}\cdot\mathbf{e_B}| + |e'_A| + |\mathbf{s_B}\cdot\mathbf{e_A}| + |e'_B|$.

Now, for Euclidean norms, [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says $|\mathbf{a\cdot b}| \leq |\mathbf{a}|\cdot |\mathbf{b}|$, so we have, for example, $|\mathbf{s_A}\cdot\mathbf{e_B}| \leq |\mathbf{s_A}| \cdot |\mathbf{e_B}| \leq  (\alpha q \sqrt{n})\cdot (\alpha q \sqrt{n})$, the last inequality coming from Lemma 1.

Let's tackle $e'_A$ and $e'_B$. I could sample a vector $\mathbf{e'}$ from $\mathcal{D_{\mathbb{Z^n},\alpha q}}$ and Lemma 1 would apply to it; if $e'_A$ is a member of $\mathbf{e'}$, it is certainly smaller than $||\mathbf{e'}||$:

$|e'_A| \leq ||\mathbf{e'_A}|| \leq \alpha q \sqrt{n} \leq (\alpha q \sqrt{n})\cdot (\alpha q \sqrt{n})$. Same for $e'_B$.

Thus I have four terms, all $\leq (\alpha q \sqrt{n})\cdot (\alpha q \sqrt{n})$. Multiply back in that $2$ and you have the result.

### Edit

They do a similar procedure later on in Section 4, and explicitly write out norms, for future reference.

Comment: Sir 
I understand that value of  |SA* eB|≤|SA| |eB|≤(αq√n). (αq√n) as ||SA||≤(αq√n) and ||eB||≤(αq√n) but how would alone |e'B|≤(αq√n). (αq√n). 
Thanks

Comment: I was making a transitive argument: if $A \leq B$ and $B \leq C$, then $A \leq C$.  Since $|e'_B| \leq ||\mathbb{e'_B}||$ (true since $e'_B$ is a member of $\mathbb{e'_B}$, and $\mathbb{e'_B} \leq \alpha q \sqrt{n}$ (from Lemma 1, and $\alpha q \sqrt{n} \leq \alpha q \sqrt{n} \cdot \alpha q \sqrt{n}$ (true for numbers bigger than 1), we have $|e'_B| \leq  \alpha q \sqrt{n} \cdot \alpha q \sqrt{n}$. Does that make sense? It's a chain of inequalities.

Comment: Also: only $e'_B$ is in the paper, and is a scalar. $\mathbb{e'_B}$ is a vector I introduced so that I could use Lemma 1; recall that it deals with vector samples. In the paper, they drew the scalar $e'_B$ directly from $\mathcal{D_{\mathbb{Z},\alpha q}}$. Instead, I drew a vector $\mathbb{e'_B}$ from $\mathcal{D_{\mathbb{Z^n},\alpha q}}$ to use Lemma 1.

Comment: ok sir understood. Thanks for putting up lot of effort.

Comment: I have confusion in lemma 2 on page number 6. Can you please explain its proof.

Comment: @vivek, as you're asking a different question, please post a new question about it. Thanks!

Comment: Please see the related posted question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/a-simple-provably-secure-key-exchange-scheme-based-on-the-lwe. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This lemma is used to conclude that a sample from $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{Z}^n,\alpha q}$ is (with overwhelming probability) less than or equal to $\alpha q \sqrt{n}$.

Now, because all values $\textbf{s}_{\textbf{A}},\textbf{s}_{\textbf{B}},\textbf{e}'_{\textbf{A}},\textbf{e}'_{\textbf{B}}$ are sampled from $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{Z}^n,\alpha q}$ , so $\textbf{s}_{\textbf{A}}^T\textbf{e}_{\textbf{B}}$ is less than or equal to $(\alpha q \sqrt{n})(\alpha q \sqrt{n})$. This bound is also true for each of  other values
$\textbf{e}_{\textbf{A}}^T\textbf{s}_{\textbf{B}}, \textbf{e}'_{\textbf{A}},\textbf{e}'_{\textbf{B}}$ and so the upper bound is determined.

Comment: Oops! Didn't see your answer. I spent about an hour trying to figure out how to type $\mathcal{D_{\mathbb{Z^n},\alpha q}}$.

Comment: @hamidreza I accept galvatron explanation as answer, as it contains detailed explanation. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @hamidreza Please see the related posted question on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48147/a-simple-provably-secure-key-exchange-scheme-based-on-the-lwe. Thanks