# A Simple Provably Secure Key Exchange Scheme Based on the LWE

Tags: key-exchange, lwe

In [this](http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/b1e7/faec59a9bdd70e75f9d15496cf27916ce060.pdf) paper (A simple provably secure key exchange by Ding et al.), I am trying to understand the correctness (which is given on page number 8) of the key exchange technique based on LWE.

To understand the correctness of the scheme, there is a very important lemma (on page number 6). The lemma is as follows:

> Lemma 2. Let $q>8$ be an odd integer, the function $E$ defined above is a robust extractor with respect to $S$ with error tolerance $\frac{q}{4}-2$.

I'm confused by the proof of Lemma 2:

1. How does the author derive the condition that Lemma 2 is true for $q\gt 8$?
2. How does $|y+ \sigma$ $\frac{(q-1)}{2} \mod q| \le \frac{q}{4}+1$?
3. At the end of the proof of Lemma 2, the author writes that

> Our robust extractor enjoys a very nice property which says that for uniformly random $x\in$$    
>  \mathbb{Z} _q$, $E(x, \sigma$) is uniform in $\{0,1\}$ even conditioned on $\sigma$, where $\sigma \leftarrow S(x)$.

This property becomes Lemma 3 of this paper.

Can anyone  answer the above three questions and thus the proof of Lemma 2 and Lemma 3? Thanks!

Comment: Please see this question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48566/provably-secure-password-authenticated-key-exchange-based-on-rlwe-for-the-post-q

Answer (score 3):

Lemma 3 in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/589.pdf) gives a better explanation regarding to your question 1 and 2.

For a simple answer for question 3, because we have equally divided region, this gives us even change on $k_i$ and $k_j$ be even or odd number, thus the output of function $E$ is uniform random.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} _q$ used in the above paper is not the mathematical $\mathbb{Z} _q$ whose range is [-(q-1), (q-1)]. But it is a $\mathbb{Z} _q$, whose range is [$\frac{-(q-1)}{2}$, $\frac{q-1}{2}$]

Comment: Also, v+Cha(v)*$\frac{q-1}{2}$ mod q $\le$ $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$. But in the above paper(paper link given by me), |y+$\sigma$ $\frac{q-1}{2}$ mod q| $\le \frac{q}{4}$+1. The  v+Cha(v)*$\frac{q-1}{2}$ mod q $\le$ $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$ seems correct but  i am not able to understand |y+$\sigma$ $\frac{q-1}{2}$ mod q| $\le \frac{q}{4}$+1.

Comment: I think $\sigma_0$(x)=0, x$\in$ [-$\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$, $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$]  is rather $\sigma_0$(x)=0, x$\in$ [-$\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$, $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rceil$] in the above paper(paper given by me). Please comment. Thanks!

Comment: @vivek output of Cha() is either output of function $\sigma_0$ or $\sigma_1$. I think the paper is clear.

Comment: @ 9f241e21 I am saying that closed interval should be [-$\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$,   $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rceil$] rather than [-$\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$,   $\lfloor$$\frac{q}{4}$$\rfloor$]. I verified this but substituting different values. Thanks

Comment: @ 9f241e21 please see this question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48566/provably-secure-password-authenticated-key-exchange-based-on-rlwe-for-the-post-q

Comment: @vivek Yes I saw it. I think the answer is pretty good for your question. Also r u following works of JT Ding?

Comment: @ 9f241e21 Yes Brother. I am working on key exchange technique in post quantum cryptography. Specifically, lattice based cryptography. Thanks

Comment: @vivek Nice one！